# non-static variable object1 cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

I'm having a little trouble getting my application to work.

I get the `error: error: non-static variable object1 cannot be referenced from a static context`

I did get the error:

```
error: object_game is not abstract and does not override abstract method keyPressed(KeyEvent) in KeyListener
public class car_game extends JFrame implements Runnable, KeyListener
```

but I fixed that because I needed `keyTyped, keyPressed, keyReleased` defined.

Here is my code:

```
public class car_game extends JFrame implements Runnable, KeyListener
{
    public object object1;

    //Main program
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        object1 = new Object() {};


        Thread t = new Thread(new object_game());
        t.start();
    }
```

Comment: `public static object object1;`

Comment: Have you looked through _all_ the `Related` questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "main" method is considered static and so it can only access static objects, Try declaring your object1 static:

```
public static Object object1;
```

edit: if you need 2 objects there is no harm in doing:

```
public static Object object1;
public static Object object2;
```

Do not get mixed up between a static field and a static class (like a Singleton). Static in this context (static Object object1) only means that there is one and only instance of that object per instance of your class car_game, in the case above their would be 2 instance of Object (object1 and object2) even if you would instanciate 10 object of type "car_game".

For example if i'd do:

```
car_game carGameObject1 = new car_game();
car_game carGameObject2 = new car_game();
carGameObject1.setObject1("this is one");
```

And then:

```
System.out.println(carGameObject2.getObject1());
```

it would print "this is one" because since object1 is static all instances of the class in which that fields belong will share the same instance.

Comment: I need two objects, though, static does not allow this?

Comment: So you need an object1 and another instance of that object: object2? If so, there is nothing that restraint you from doing it. Do not mix a static object between a singleton, this is not the same thing.

Comment: yes object 1 and object 2: will that work? I've been told it will not

Answer (score 0):

`public object object1` make this as `public static object object1;`

You can not refer non-static class variables inside static method.